# Translating an Abarbanel in Melachim

Tags: commentaries, translation, navi-prophets, melachim-kings-book-of

I'm having trouble translating this paragraph, particularly because of the phrases I am bolding. It is the אברבנאל on מלכים א פרק ב פסוק ו:
ואחרי שספר דוד כל המעשה הזה אשר עשה יואב נגדו, אמר לשלמה בנו ועשית בחכמתך, רוצה לומר אל תתנהג בעצתו ואל תחשוב שהוא חכם חרשים ושהיה שר צבאי ואתה נער ורך ושתצדק בהיותך נמשך אחריו, לא תעשה כן, אבל התחזק והיית לאיש ועשית הדברים כלם כחכמתך ולא כחכמתו, וכדי להשמר ממנו איעצך ויהי אלקים עמך שלא יהיה עמך בשלום, **ולהיותו גם שב גם ישיש הרחק מעליו דרכך ולא תשב עמו בשלום אבל תגרשהו**, ואז לא ימשול בך כאשר משל בי, ולפי זה לו צוה דוד את שלמה שיהרגהו כי אם שלא ישב עמו בשלום, וגם זה לא צוה עליו להענישו כי אם לתת עצה לשלמה שישמר ממנו, והותרה עם זה השאלה החמשית: והנוצרים פירשו שאולה הנזכר בכאן על הגיהנום ועולם העונש הנפשיי, ואמרו שצוה לשלמה שיהרוג את יואב ויענש על חטאיו אשר עשה בזה העולם, באופן שלהיותו נענש בעולם הזה לא יענש בעולם הבא, ו**זהו ולא תורד שיבתו בסבת השלום אשר לו בכאן לשאול תחתית**, ומה שזכרתי אני הוא הנכון:

Also, why does he quote the Christians instead of other mepharshim who say this?

Comment: ולהיותו גם שב גם ישיש הרחק מעליו דרכך ולא תשב עמו בשלום אבל תגרשהו - Since he is gray and elderly, keep far away from him otherwise you will subservient to his judgement, and you should not live with him in peace (for this reason), rather you should drive him away.

Comment: וזהו ולא תורד שיבתו בסבת השלום אשר לו בכאן לשאול תחתית - You should not cause him to go to *gehinnom* on account of your living peaceably with him, which would cause you to come under his sway and not be able to atone him of his evil deeds.

Comment: "why does he quote the Christians" - I think this is relatively common for the Abarbanel.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Burt and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bolded line is:

> ולהיותו גם שב גם ישיש הרחק מעליו דרכך ולא תשב עמו בשלום אבל תגרשהו

It translates as:

And because he is old and venerated (held in great respect), distance your ways from him. And don't sit (work) with him in peace (meaning partnership), but separate from him...

Your second bolded line is:

> וזהו ולא תורד שיבתו בסבת השלום אשר לו בכאן לשאול תחתית

This is more complex in its translation because it is dependent on the defective spelling from the text in 1-Melachim 2:5-6.

David is explaining to his son, Shlomo that Yoav ambushed and murdered Avner and Amasa in demonstrating his support for David. He goes on to say that Yoav did this as a *political calculation* for the sake of ***peace***.

This is why, in the text, the word for peace (שלום) is spelled defectively, missing the letter Vav (שלם). This type of action (political assassination) does not lead to true peace. David describes this type of peace with the same missing letter Vav which means in translation, ***a borrowed peace*** (בשלם שאל). If it were spelled correctly, it should be (שלום שאול).

David says to Shlomo, not to work with Yoav in partnership, like he himself had done and not to trust him. But to distance himself from Yoav. And in this way, Yoav would not control him.

Further, David advises his son to deal with Yoav according to his wisdom and to not allow Yoav to die peacefully on account of Yoav's actions concerning the ***borrowed peace***, but rather to kill him. In other words, it becomes a **Midah Keneged Midah**. And this explanation of the text answers (literally releases) the fifth question that Abarbanel posed at the beginning of this book.

But what Abarbanel is bringing up after this is the mis-translation of the text that is used by the Christians (meaning the Catholics). They also recognize the defective spelling, but think it is referring to the level of Hell called ***Sha'olah***.

It is important to remember Abarbanel's commentary in its historical context. Abarbanel was dealing with the persecution by the Catholic court against the Jews in Spain which ultimately led to the expulsion and/or forced conversion of many Spanish Jews. Being one of the leaders from the house of David in Spain, he was called upon by the Spanish Monarch to defend the theology of Judaism against the Catholic doctrine of the time in his famous disputes.

Abarbanel explains that the Catholics use this type of mis-translation to support the principle that if someone receives their punishment in this world, that they are freed from punishment in the World to Come.

This is the basis of their argument that Yeshu received all the punishments in this world in order to free everyone else from judgement and Hell in the World to Come. In this context, Peace (שלום), is used in the sense of *completion* or *paying off the debt*.

So the second bolded line is explaining the meaning of ***their*** mis-translation.

And this (means), this one who is venerated here (meaning because he receives no punishment in this world for his transgressions, then he should receive it in Hell. But rather, he), will not descend to the depths of Hell on account of ***the peace*** (השלום).

According to their mis-translation, the word, peace, is now spelled fully with the Vav to indicate true peace. And it is also preceded with the **Indicative letter Heh**, to indicate that special, known ***Peace*** or ***Perfection***, known to Christians, namely Yeshu.

And Abarbanel closes by emphasizing, "that which I recalled is the correct (explanation)."